# CSS selector :not(...) [parent has some class]

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select all tags with class *p*, that is child of *.row*

```
.row .p {
   ...
}
```

but exclude all, that have *.disable* as parent class (not directly).

I can select both of them like that:

```
.row .p {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.disable .row .p {
  border: 3px solid red;;
}
```

**But we want to use just one selector**

**NOTE:** between .disable and .row can be any elements.

**CLEARIFICATION:** .disable .row .p should have no color at all. So if .disable is present somehow in the parent line do NOT make a blue border. just leave it away.

example: 
https://codepen.io/miladfm/pen/ELbwMx

Comment: one selector you cannot

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PeOOOd.

Comment: there is no parent selector neither and ancestor selector too

Comment: Do you mean like this `div:not(.disable) .row > .p` ... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJXXzB?editors=1100

Comment: It does not work because of this example: div.disable div div.row div.p

Comment: Also this does not work because div.row div.p has potentially no parent at all.

Comment: @LGSon as you can see, you colored the first p red and i has a disable ancestor because the not condition apply to any element within the disable and p

Comment: well it was not the correct duplicate but it still impossible

Comment: I give in @TemaniAfif. It is impossible. Unfortunately.

Comment: Works like this though. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PeOOOd. @TemaniAfif

Comment: Ok then. Thank you guys for your effort! :)

Comment: @AjAX. yes this is a trivial case as we deal with one level, so we won't have issue with sub levels

Comment: You are defining 2 different colours on the same elements, which means you will need 2 rules for them. There is no way to do it with one rule

Comment: Yeah @TemaniAfif. I was at first inspired.

Comment: @TemaniAfif No it doesnt. See: https://codepen.io/miladfm/pen/GdOOVz

Comment: it does with one level ;) and yes if you add more level it won't

Comment: @Huangism the second color was just example. What I want is no color at all if there is a disable somewhere as a parent.

Comment: @TemaniAfif The problem is in my code I could have any number of divs in between :(

Comment: yes I know, and my answer is clear: it's impossible :) I am simply relying to other trying to find a way ;) .. by the way I still believe in CSS magic, maybe it's possible but my mind still didn't find how

Comment: @miladfm By saying _"I could have any number of divs in between"_ makes it impossible to do using CSS. You will need a script.

Comment: @LGSon You might be right :(

Comment: @miladfm I am _right_, today :), but when we can do `:has` it might be possible

Answer (score 0):

[Using CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) (aka CSS Variables) you can style an element according to some ancestor if you set a value to this ancestor and get its value on the former. It's inherited throughout *the mighty cascade®* and if not set, you can have a default value given by the fallback of `var(--custom-prop, fallback)`

Support is Edge 15+ or 16+ and other modern browsers for a longer time AFAIK

```
/* If any ascendant has a given class, no border */
.disable {
  --parent-disable-border: none;
}

/* Default border with fallback value of a CSS Variable / Custom Property */
.p {
  border: var(--parent-disable-border, 3px solid blue);
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/PeOQdK?editors=1000) (sorry no snippet it currently fails in Firefox)

Comment: And we still have 2 selector to control, so I agree CSS variable are good but it doesn't solve the issue here

Comment: thats good but as @Temani Afif mentioned, we have still 2 selector